# How to get screen reader from reading inline span elements separately?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

I have the following paragraph:

```html
<p>Random text that has <span class="font--bold">some bold text</span> and continues on...</p>
```

I am using the [ChromeVox extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox-classic-extensi/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en) to ensure my site is accessible. By the nature of the font type used, I need to use a separate `<span class="font--bold">` element to have that text be bold.

My problem is when I navigate to this paragraph using Chromevox, it will focus on and read the text before the `<span>`, then the text inside the `<span>`, and then the rest of the paragraph.

Outcome:

- I navigate onto the `<p>` element.
- Chromevox focuses and reads: "Random text that has".
- I navigate to the next item.
- Chromevox focuses and reads: "some bold text".
- I navigate to the next item.
- Chromevox focuses and reads the remaining text in the `<p>`.

Desired outcome:

- Navigate onto paragraph element.
- Chromevox focuses entire paragraph, and reads it outloud.

---

There is no issue when this format is used inside header tags (e.g. `<h2><span class="font--bold">My</span> title</h2>`. Chromevox reads this out as one section.

I've tried adding in `role="text"` and `tabindex="-1"` into the `<span>` element, but that didn't work. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, interesting one. Have you tried `role="presentation"`?

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work.

Comment: If it's not respecting that or `role="none"` either than it may be time to heed their disclaimer in their own description for more comprehensive standards compliance; -  "For more comprehensive solutions, we recommend the use of full system screen readers like ChromeVox **on Chrome OS**, VoiceOver on Mac, JAWS, NVDA or Narrator on Windows, etc."

Comment: Seems to be a ChromeVox bug, my preferred screen reader (JAWS for Windows) would read it normally. And please, *don't* overuse the `presentation` role!

Answer (score 2):

## role="text" tag

Sometimes the simplest answers are the best, you are looking for `role="text"`

```
<p>Random text that has <span class="font--bold" role="text">some bold text</span> and continues on...</p>
```

### Side Note

`role="text"` will remove all semantic meaning from an element so make sure it is used carefully (i.e. don't use on a `h1` tag as it will then change it to behave like any other element)